# Asynchronous read file with boost asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I would like to read a large file in C++ in an asynchronous manner. I already use boost::asio to perform async reads from network sockets, and I wonder if it is possible to extend boost::asio to do non-blocking reads on regular files.

I could use a separate thread to do the job, but is there a more native solution, that would fit well with `asio::io_service` ?

I am using Linux, but I won't reject a portable solution with `std::ifstream` ;)

Comment: did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001387/how-to-use-asio-with-device-files ?

Comment: this question was about device files, but I want to read any file

Answer (score -1):

Linux does not support non-blocking file reads. `boost::asio` does not support async read files on linux, too.

You can use aio_read(3) manually, but it creates a system thread to do the job.

Comment: You're sure Linux does not support non-blocking file io ? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/aio.7.html

Comment: @RichardHodges its same as aio_read. Its not "true" asynchronous.

Comment: It seems to me that The documentation does not agree with your position. Don't we code to interfaces and allow the implementation latitude in doing its work?